# Как по другому выполнить запрос в Oracle?

Tags: oracle, sql

Есть две таблицы - А и В.

```
create table a (
    KEY1 number
);

create table b (
    KEY2 number,
    KEY3 number
);
```

Нужно проверить, что для каждой записи таблицы А нет записей в таблице B по условию A.KEY1 = B.KEY2. Если же записи есть, то для каждой такой записи таблицы В проверить что нет записей в таблице А по условию В.KEY3 = A.KEY1.

Реализовал так:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT *
 FROM   B 
 WHERE  A.KEY1 = B.KEY2
 AND    B.KEY3 NOT IN (SELECT KEY1 FROM   A))
```

Есть другие варианты выполнить этот же запрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from A where key1 not in(select key2 from B)
union all
(
select * from A where key1 in(select key2 from B)
intersect
select * from a where key1 not in(select key3 from b)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Для такой комбинации данных:

```
A    |  B
key1 |  key2    key3
1    |  3       2 
2    |  4       7
3    |  5       8
```

ожидается `a.Key1` 1 и 2, т.е две строчки. Правильно надо так:

```
select * from a where not exists (select 1 from b where key1=key2)
union all
select * from a where exists (
    select 1 from b 
    where a.key1=b.key2 
    and not exists (select 1 from a aa where aa.key1=b.key3)
    );
```